# How to fetch data with React Query after a clicking on the search button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I want to fetch new data using the new parameter being passed to the `useFetch` hook which has a default fetch when the app mounts for the first time. The second fetch and more fetches are supposed to happen when the user fills in the input to enter a new city and submits, then that city's data is brought back.

`useFetch Hook`

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const useFetch = function (city:string='kampala') {
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["weatherData"],
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch(
        `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=516e576e876042b9b7665337232403&q=${city}&days=7`
      ).then((res) => res.json()),
  });

  return { isLoading, error, data };
};

export default useFetch;
```

The search component below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BsSearch } from "react-icons/bs";
import useFetch from "../../../hooks/useFetch";

import "./header.css";

type Props = {};

function Header({}: Props) {
  // const [city, setCity] = useState("kampala");

  const city = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    useFetch(city.current?.value);
    // city.current.value = "";
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="lovez">
      <div className="lovek">
        <h1 style={{ color: "#F5AF26" }}>Weather Forcast</h1>
        <p>{new Date("2023-03-24").toDateString()}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="header__search">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="home__input"
            ref={city}
            name="city"
            placeholder="Choose City"
          />
          <button type="submit" className="weather__button">
            Search
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should save `city` in state instead of ref, so that when you change it, the component is re-rendered.

Second, you should pass `city` to the `queryKey` paramater, react-query will automatically resend the request when the city changes. You can read more about this [here](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-keys).

It should look something like the following:

```
const useFetch = function (city:string='kampala') {
  const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["weatherData", city],
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch(
        `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=516e576e876042b9b7665337232403&q=${city}&days=7`
      ).then((res) => res.json()),
  });

  return { isLoading, error, data };
};
```

```
const [city, setCity] = useState("kampala");
const {data} = useFetch(city);

const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setCity(e.target.city.value);

  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are violating [rules of hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) by calling `useFetch` inside a "standard JavaScript" function `handleSubmit` that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. You `useFetch` becomes a hook as you have written another hook inside it `useQuery`.

I would suggest you to rename `useFetch` to something more relatable like `useCityWeather`.

For the actual solution, you can do following as suggested by @Enve: use a local state to store the city data and whenever it's updated, all the hooks inside the component including `useFetch` will be called again with the updated state.

In case you want to initialize the state with a data passed by `props`, you can write like this:

```js
const [city, setCity] = useState(props.city || ''); // Optional || ''
```